# URL with fragment chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a little problem whit my chrome extension.
The extension works if I'm on a URL that not uses fragment. 
Now sure on how to configure it.

Im trying with definition  **< all_urls >** but as I wrote. it does not work on pages with fragment.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

    "name": "Analytic Live Alarm",
    "version": "0.3",
    "description": "Felipe the solution provider",
    "permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "icons": { 
                "16": "icon.png",
                "48": "icon.png",
                "128": "icon_128.png" 
            },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
        "run_at": "document_end" ,
          "js": ["jquery.min.js", "script.js"]     
        }
    ], 
    "manifest_version":2
}
```

This is the url Im using. 
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#dashboard/6I8yfVs_TqSQ_b1tOJYR0Q/a8398197w15972131p74378741/

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383418/change-color-of-element-chrome-extension)..

It's not "not working", it's working *once*; then, as you navigate, the page is not really reloaded, and your script does *not* run again.

Instead of coloring all elements at `document_end`, you need to detect new elements that match your selector and re-apply your styles.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener) should help you get started, or better yet [mutation-summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) library.